# Проблема с placeholder

Tags: html, css

У меня есть код для поля ввода, при нажатии на это поле placeholder текст смещается на границу поля ввода, но есть проблема, placeholder находится не поверх границы, а под ней. z-index не помогает. Заранее спасибо!

```css
.input{
  transform: translate(0%, 150%)
}

.input[type="text"]{
  padding-left: 5%;
}

.input::placeholder{
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.input:focus::placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  color:#7beec7;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(0%, -110%);
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
        <div class="inputcontainer">
            <input placeholder="Your Email" type="text" name="email" class="input">
        </div>
```

Comment: а почему нельзя сделать top - 20px ?

Comment: Top тоже не работает

Comment: так ты хочешь что бы он поднялся над инпутом?

Comment: вот так это делается : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/poNMdmp

Comment: а сам placehilder из input ни как не выйдет